# insert function for linked list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

```
struct Node {
    float  item;
    Node * next;
    Node * previous;
};
```

I am trying to write a function `insert` for this double linked list which inserts the float data to position pos on the list which uses the header `bool insert (int pos, float data);` Which the function should return true if the insertion is successful, false otherwise

But i am trying to replicate something i saw online but I am just having no success could someone show me a sample code maybe to understand or get an idea of how to do this?

Here is what i got so far. The function should return true if the insertion is successful, false otherwise. But i dont think i approached this right

```
  bool insert ( int pos, float data)
{
    if(pos< 1||pos> 1) throw...
        if (pos ==1)
        {
            ListNode* node=new Listnode;
            node-> data=item;
            node-> next-head;
            if(head!=NULL)
                head->prev=node;
            node-> prev=NULL;
            head=node;
            ++count;
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to understand how a linked list works and how to implement this code but im at a loss which the function header and what its asking a sample would really benefit me perhaps.

Comment: Hard to answer this question without seeing the code you have already written. There are many ways to implement a doubly linked list.

Comment: How could i implement it using this struct?

Comment: There are many ways to implement it using this struct. It would help if you post what you have been trying so far, even if it's incorrect.

Comment: If you saw that online, there must a sample code there too right? Then why ask here? You should search more, there are tons of samples everywhere.

Comment: I have sample codes of other linked lists but im trying to figure this one out in my textbook for this question but i dont know how to work it with this struct but i have other samples with other structs im trying to figure this out on my own

Comment: The onein my textbook uses `struct ListNode
    {
        T item;
        ListNode * next;
    } ;

    ListNode *head;
    int size;`

Comment: I will put my code that i came up with hold on

Comment: I added the code i came up with

Comment: So where are head and count declared? Looks like you have some class somewhere you haven't told us about. Or is that the issue? You don't know where to declare head and count.

Comment: The function should return true if the insertion is successful, false otherwise.

Comment: Yeah im working from the textbook and this struct thats why im confused on what im doing.

Comment: Well the basic issue is that you need two structs (or prefereably two classes). You need one struct for the list as a whole, that's where head and count go (count is presumably the size of the list), and another struct for the nodes. The insert function you've written above will be a member function of your list class. I've put a quick sample to get you started as an answer.

Comment: This line looks suspicious: `node-> next-head;` It doesn't actually do anything (well it does some nonsense, but nothing is saved).

Comment: Why not use a class and implement private functions to handle things like memory (I see a "new", so have to code a "delete"),... . Have a closer look at STL std::vector. This is a very good example!

Comment: Also, unless you write this as a learning exercise you should look into [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or any of the other [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to get you started

```
struct Node {
    float  item;
    Node * next;
    Node * previous;
};

class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    DoublyLinkedList();
    bool insert(int pos, float data);
private:
    Node* head;
    int count;
};

bool DoublyLinkedList::insert(int pos, float data)
{
    ...
}
```

But I think you have a lot of learning to do about C++ before you'll complete this. Maybe better to look at a complete example online.

Comment: Ah i see i had to have a a class as well for this. Alright ill try to learn it off this but inside i gotta figure this out lmfao